mention new job in cover letter for TT position?
I am currently a postdoc but will begin an industry job in January. I'm applying to some tenure track jobs this cycle, and the timing is such that my application will be submitted while I'm a postdoc but (likely) evaluated while I am at my new position. Should I address this explicitly in my cover letter, and if so, how? I have previously emailed with people on a few of the hiring committees as well, so I could also "unofficially" mention my situation to them.

Unless the job is especially relevant to an academic position, I'd suggest not mentioning it; especially in the cover letter. Make the cover letter all about the new job and your desire and suitability for the position.
People will assume that, because of a break in time, that you will do something to make a living. What that is can be irrelevant. Just be prepared to answer questions when asked.
